# Angular Routing Not Working With Express

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am trying to create a single page app using Angular. routing I'm using Node/Express on the back-end. While Express is serving my static index.html correctly, my partial .html pages are not being pulled into my ng-view.

Here is the HTML where the view is being pulled in along with the call to the angular app:

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-inverse navbar-fixed-top topnav" role="navigation">
        <div class="container topnav">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand topnav" href="/">DtepDC</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/movies">Movies App</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="mailto:dawn714@gmail.com">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div ng-view></div>
```

Here is my Angular routing code:

```
        app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "intro-header.html"
        })
        .when("/movies", {
            templateUrl: "#!/movies.html",
            controller: "moviesCtrl"
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirect: '/'
        });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);
```

Here is my Express server.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.set('port', 3000);
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/'));

app.use(function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
var port = server.address().port;
console.log('Running server at http://localhost:' + port + '/');
});
```

Here is my factory code and I have include the call to the Angular app:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]);

app.factory("getMovie", ["$http",function($http){
    var obj = {};
    var url = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/movies/v2/reviews/search.json";
    obj.getMovieInfo = function(title){ 
        return $http({
            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            params:{ 
                query: title,
                api_key: "68094e1974e7984c256beb1653319915:3:33678189",
                callback: "JSON_CALLBACK"
          },
            headers: {
                "Content-Type" : "application/json"
            }
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    return response.data.results; 
             }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    console.log("Nothing to see here...");
             });
            }
        return obj;
}]);
```

Here is my controller code:

```
        app.controller("moviesCtrl", ["$scope", "getMovie",     function($scope, getMovie){
    $scope.findMovie = function() {
        getMovie.getMovieInfo($scope.title).then(function(response){
            $scope.results = response;
        });
    }    
}]);
```

Here is my HTML block with the controller:

```
    <h2>Movie Search</h2>
        <!-- START row -->
        <div ng-controller="moviesCtrl">
            <div>
                <div class="col-sm-12" class="form-group">                
                    <form name="myForm" class="form-inline">

                        Find a NYTimes movie review based on its title (or part of a title): <input type="string" class="form-control" ng-model="title">
                        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="findMovie()" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div ng-cloak ng-repeat="result in results | filter: { display_title: title }" class="row results">
                            <img src="{{ result.multimedia.src }}" height="{{ result.multimedia.height }}" width="{{ result.multimedia.width }}" class="pull-left"/>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 pull-left">
                                <div><strong><em><a href="{{ result.link.url }}">{{ result.display_title }}</a></em></strong></div>
                             {{ result.summary_short }}</div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us your js with your controllers and your html,

Comment: I just updated, thanks and let me know if you need anything else. Thanks!

Comment: The part of the html with the ng_view could be useful to.

Comment: Also in your movies.html you do not need to put a ng-controller attribute, it will be added automatically on the ng-view load

Comment: Do you get any errors into the console?

Comment: Oh right, thanks. I had initially built this without the routing so there could be a few more things I don't now need. I've updated my code to include part of the index.html page with the ng-view and call to the Angular app.

Comment: No errors in my console. I can see that the page is trying as my URL's are rendering as such: http://localhost:3000/movies#!/ and http://localhost:3000/#!/ but the entire page is reloading.

Comment: Can you add * to the get('/' such as it becomes get('/* and let me know what happens?

Comment: that url isn't right;  it should be http://localhost:3000/#!/movies.  Does it help if you add `<base href="/"></base>` in the `head` of your HTML?  or change your href in the a to `#!/movies`?

Comment: @Claies if html 5 mode is activated it's ok, the #! Won't be there

Comment: @Sorikairo yes, but html5Mode isn't active in the code here;  also html5Mode won't work with this configuration.  Part of the way that html5Mode works is by the server returning index for unknown routes, which can't work when everything is in `/`, including the templates.

Comment: The `app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});` is going to be a problem, I believe.....

Comment: I added the /* and included the base href code with no luck. Now, if I view http://localhost:3000/#!/movies in the browser, it works! But I can't do that manually so there is something about the angular that seems off.

Comment: but @Sorikairo is correct, the `a href="/movies"` *assumes* that you are trying to use html5Mode.  have you tried adding `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` to your angular route config?

Comment: I should mention that while the page is rendered correctly when I manually enter http://localhost:3000/#!/movies, the page also crashes. No errors in the console or terminal.

Comment: @Claies, I will add that now...

Comment: I just updated my routing/config above with the included $location.Provider.html5Mode(true); code. No change and the page crashes when I click on the Movies link.

Comment: I think this might have something to do with Express' confusion with partials and is contributing to the page crashing...

Comment: Remove the 2 app.use please

Comment: I removed both the page renders with only bare bones content and no partial html files (and routes don't work). If I keep one, the page renders correctly.

Comment: About your links, could you instead add ng-click that Call a function that do $location.path("/movies");

Comment: I'm trying to create a single page application using Angular routing so if I create an ng-click function, then maybe I just need to think about another way to do this or get rid of Express so I can get this up and working. I need to step away but thank you for your help and check back in a bit.

Comment: Your SPA should be working actually, that's express that is preventing something to go well

Comment: Yes, I think it has to do with confusion with partials. I'll read up more on it and see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: I have solved this: I moved my Angular views into a folder under "/" and Express stopped trying to serve the files on their end. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add this to your routes

```
/* ANGULAR MAIN ROUTE */
router.get('*', function(req, res) {
   res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
});
```